# Azure ML endpoint get probability for classification

Tags: python, azure, probability

Is there a way to get probabilities for binary classification on a azure ml endpoint using python?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can get the probabilities from the Visualize by right-clicking on Score Model.
[image]
Here is the designer flow

1. Upload the dataset.
2. Edit the Metadata (i.e. the columns which are needed to be made Categorical).
3. Clean missing values and Remove the unnecessary Columns.
4. Make the label then build the Model by splitting the model to make accurate predictions by training the model.
5. As we are seeing for a binary classification there will be 2 possible solutions (i.e. YES/NO). Hence we will have a decision model for decision making.
6. Now let's Score and Evaluate the Model.
7. The part other than for training will be sent to the score model for the predictions.
8. Now right click on Evaluation Model and click Visualize. In there you can get all the results including the graph.
9. You can view all the records probabilities by clicking on Visualize of the score model.

You can refer [HERE](https://www.foteinisavvidou.codes/predict-the-risk-of-chronic-kidney-disease-with-azure-machine-learning/) for more information.